React Router DOM Doesn't Renders On Navigate
I have a really basic setup for routing in my React app. Navigate parts in ProtectedRoutes are navigating but it doesn't render anything on the window. Also when i move the Route tags out of their nested Routes it works. Help pls.
ProtectedRoutes.tsx
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token")

    var currentLocation = window.location.href
    
    

    if(token) {
        const decoded = (jwtDecode(token) as any)
        

        if(decoded.signup_completed) {
            if(
                currentLocation.endsWith("/login") ||  
                currentLocation.endsWith("/forgot-password") || 
                currentLocation.endsWith("/reset-password") || 
                currentLocation.endsWith("/signup")
            )
            {
                return <Navigate to='/'/>
            }
        } else {
            if(decoded.signup_step === 2) {
                return <Navigate to='/signup/company'/>
            } else if(decoded.signup_step === 3) {
                return <Navigate to='/signup/company/detail'/>
            }
        }

        
        
    } else {
        if(currentLocation.endsWith('/login') || currentLocation.endsWith('/signup') || currentLocation.endsWith('/reset-password') || currentLocation.endsWith('/forgot-password')) {
            return <Outlet/>            
        }
        return <Navigate to='/login'/>
    }

    
    



    return <Outlet /> 
}


export default ProtectedRoutes

And
Àpp.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
          <Route index element={<Clients />} />

          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          

          
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          
          <Route path="/signup/company" element={<SignupCompany />} />
          <Route
            path="/signup/company/detail"
            element={<SignupCompanyDetail />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;


I don't have any errors on console and I'm using react-router-dom: "^6.23.1"

Can you point out or indicate where you need specific help or where specifically in your code you have a problem? What debugging steps have you taken already to diagnose any issue(s)? It's probably not helpful that your ProtectedRoutes routes component is trying to navigate to sign/log-in routes it's protecting. These are typically defined outside the route protector that checks for users to be authenticated. Maybe your ProtectedRoutes component is trying to do too much.

I have tried to remove the wrapper  tag for protected routes and i was able to render the page. When i wrap it with protected routes tag the navigations work URL is changing but it doesn't renders anything on the page. I think its about the navigation. Basically the routes that are not wrapped inside protected routes are rendering but inside they are not. Also im already logging to console to see if it renders too much but its not.

Right... I think it is because you never get to a case where the Outlet is rendered so the nested routes can render out their content. Like I said, typically login and signin routes are rendered outside routes you are trying to protect against unauthorized user access. It seems to me the "/" route rendering Clients is the only route that should currently be protected. You may very well want/need a separate "SignInFlow" route component that manages redirecting users to the correct sign-in page based on current token status.

Wow let me check that.

Yep you are right i need to add Outlets to the cases. I will update the code and post it thank you very much.

As @Drew Reese mentioned i was just navigationg but not able to hit any outlets to render pages. i have updated the code like this and it works.
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token")

    var currentLocation = window.location.href
    
    

    if(token) {
        const decoded = (jwtDecode(token) as any)
        

        if(decoded.signup_completed) {
            if(
                currentLocation.endsWith("/login") ||  
                currentLocation.endsWith("/forgot-password") || 
                currentLocation.endsWith("/reset-password") || 
                currentLocation.endsWith("/signup")
            )
            {
                return <Navigate to='/'/>
            }
        } else {
            if(decoded.signup_step === 2) {
                if(currentLocation.endsWith('/signup/company')) {
                    return <Outlet/>
                }
                return <Navigate to='/signup/company'/>
            } else if(decoded.signup_step === 3) {
                if(currentLocation.endsWith('/signup/company/detail')){
                    return <Outlet/>
                }
                return <Navigate to='/signup/company/detail'/>
            }
        }

        
        
    } else {
        if(currentLocation.endsWith('/login') || currentLocation.endsWith('/signup') || currentLocation.endsWith('/reset-password') || currentLocation.endsWith('/forgot-password')) {
            return <Outlet/>            
        }
        return <Navigate to='/login'/>
    }

    
    



    return <Outlet /> 
}


export default ProtectedRoutes

